# Stopping a While loop and quitting script in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, sikuli

I am using Sikuli the OCR testing library. In my Python script I am looking for one of two possible images to appear. When one of them does appear, if chooses that object.

However, I would like for the script to end. It doesn't. I've tried `quit()` and `exit()` but that isn't doing it. It is working fine, beside the stop of the while loop and completing the script.

```
while True:
    if exists ("lose.png"):
        click ("lose.png")
        print ("***** YOU LOSE! *****")
    if exists ("win.png"):
        click ("win.png")
        print ("***** YOU WIN! *****")
    StopIteration

quit()
```

Comment: BTW, it doesn't seem that you are working with OCR. These are images, not text you are trying to detect..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can exit any loop with `break`:

```
while True:
    if exists ("lose.png"):
        click ("lose.png")
        print ("***** YOU LOSE! *****")
        break

    if exists ("win.png"):
        click ("win.png")
        print ("***** YOU WIN! *****")
        break
```

If neither of the `if` statements evaluate to `True`, the loop continues.

`StopIteration` is an exception, usually raised by iterators to signal that they are done. Most Python code that uses it only needs to *catch* that exception, but if you wanted to raise it, use a `raise StopIteration()` statement. There is no point in doing so here; your script is not being run as an iterator and the `StopIteration` exception will not have the desired effect.

Comment: Also, raising `StopIteration` inside the body of the loop won't really do what you want; it has to be raised *in the iterator.*

Comment: Yes. But that stops the execution on the two if statements. I do not want break until the script has found one of the two images. With break it stops the script with - [info] Exit code : 0 (I should have mentioned that) This is why I was trying with StopIteration.

Comment: @Dave: I already updated the answer and moved the `break` statements to *inside* the `if` statements. The `while` loop is only stopped when one of the two `if` statements is `True`.

Comment: Ha. The text did not update until I cmd+r. Thanks, Martijn! It is the break outside the if that caused this.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this:

```
status = TRUE
while status:
        if exists ("lose.png"):
            click ("lose.png")
            print ("***** YOU LOSE! *****")
            status = FALSE
        if exists ("win.png"):
            click ("win.png")
            print ("***** YOU WIN! *****")
            status = FALSE
        StopIteration
    
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `break` is used to exit loops. To exit the script, use `sys.exit()`. So:

```
while True:
    if exists ("lose.png"):
        click ("lose.png")
        print ("***** YOU LOSE!*****")
    if exists ("win.png"):
        click ("win.png")
        print ("***** YOU WIN!*****")
    break // Exit the loop
import sys; sys.exit() // Close the program
```